# Cygwin with PyCharm

Tags: java, bash

I want to run PyCharm (linux version) on Cygwin (Windows 8 x64) with Oracle java (windows version).

I've tried with correction pycharm.sh from idea of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004915/cygwin-and-java/2010652#2010652), but faced with problems:

- `unable to load main class com.intellij.idea.Main` (if put `$JAVA_HOME` and `$SCRIPT_LOCATION` to `.bashrc`)
- or eval `cygpath --absolute --windows "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java.exe"` with response ==

  `cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:\Java\jre7\bin\java
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/Java/jre7/bin/java
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
  http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
  ./pycharm.sh: line 204: C:Javajre7binjava: command not found`

(if put `JAVA_HOME` and `SCRIPT_LOCATION` to windows `PATH`)

- if simply `eval "/cygdrive/c/Java/jre7/bin/java.exe"` - response  is equilent to first case

Comment: Why would you expect the linux version to work on Windows? (See cygwin.com: 'Cygwin is not: a way to run native Linux apps on Windows.')

Comment: But I could install python, virtualenv, pip, django etc and everything works, just like on ubuntu or others. And I assumed that needless to stay on humongous vmware. Earlier I've tried ubuntu and opensuse with several linux kernels versions on my hp probook 4540s  and everytime had unsolved problems

Comment: ... last one was overheating. After installed vmware, but 4gb RAM for win8 + virtual machine is nothing))

Comment: Generally cygwin will work without changes for interpreted (e.g. python) and JIT/bytecode (e.g. Java) languages, but if there are any native calls, e.g. to a graphics library, it won't. Have you considered dual-booting?

Comment: For something as complicated as pycharm I doubt it'll work anyway, even if you had the sources it'll be a challenge.

Comment: I've solved my problems via installing hackintosh everything works and no overheat :)