# Using an Additional Java Library in Cygwin

Tags: java, windows, cygwin

I'm taking an intro Java class, and they require that we download and use their Standard Library. They want us to pipe files, which uses the command line, so I would like to use Cygwin on Windows instead of CMD. How do I link the stdlib.jar to the java compiler in Cygwin so that I can use:

```
    javac-introcs MyProgram.java
```

and

```
    java-introcs MyProgram
```

as they request in the assignment. 
Note that this code already works in CMD, however, I'm much more of a Linux terminal fan (as I'd like to use vim in Cygwin).

Also, the stdlib.java file is in C:\Users\Sam\introcs

Thank you!

Edit:
java-introcs does appear to be a batch file.

java-introcs:

```
    @echo off

    :: ***************************************************
    :: java-introcs
    :: ------------------
    :: Wrapper for java that includes stdlib.jar and
    :: the Java3D files
    :: ***************************************************

    set install=%USERPROFILE%\introcs
    set j3dlib=%install%\j3d\lib\ext

    java -cp      "%install%\stdlib.jar;%j3dlib%\vecmath.jar;%j3dlib%\j3dutils.jar;%j3dlib%\j3dcore.jar;." %*
```

javac-introcs:

```
    @echo off

    :: ***************************************************
    :: javac-introcs
    :: ------------------
    :: Wrapper for javac that includes stdlib.jar and
    :: the Java3D files
    :: ***************************************************

    set install=%USERPROFILE%\introcs
    set j3dlib=%install%\j3d\lib\ext

    javac -cp         "%install%\stdlib.jar;%j3dlib%\vecmath.jar;%j3dlib%\j3dutils.jar;%j3dlib%\j3dcore.jar;." %*
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As currently written, its hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Is `java-introcs` some kind of batch file? If so please edit your question to include the contents of the file.

Comment: I apologize that I seem unclear, as I have searched online, however, I cannot find any good help for this problem. And I'm (obviously) a noobie.

Comment: So what is **in** the batch file? please edit your question to include the **contents** of the file.

Comment: Okay, so in C:\Users\Sam\introcs, there are the following folders: bin (the interesting one)
checkstyle-5.5, 
findbugs-2.0.3, 
j3d, java, 
and there is a stlib.jar file.

Within the bin folder, there is checkstyle-introcs.bat, checkstyle-introcs.ps1, findbugs-introcs.bat, findbugs-introcs.ps1, javac-introcs.bat, and finally java-introcs.bat

Comment: Now I'm confused. You said there was a **batch file**, presumably called `java-introcs.bat`. Please open `java-introcs.bat` in notepad, copy the contents, and add the contents to your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cygwin and java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004915/cygwin-and-java)