# Run and compile java code in cygwin

Tags: java, cygwin

I just installed `cygwin` and I am wondering how do I compile and run my java code through `cygwin`?

My java code is at my desktop saved in a file named Java.

Comment: You don't need cygwin to run java. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does `javac -version` work?

Comment: @nikhil Yea I know that, I was just wondering how to do it using cygwin.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Nope.

Comment: Add the directory containing `javac` to your PATH; something like `export PATH="$PATH:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_32/bin"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [cygwin and java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004915/cygwin-and-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have Java SDK for Windows installed.

In the simplest case:

1. Ensure/Add java to PATH in cygwin:

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:"/cygdrive/C/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/"
   ```

   (don't forget the backslash after Program)
2. `cd` to your desktop:

   ```
   cd /path/to/Desktop
   ```
3. run java compiler:

   ```
   javac HelloWorld.java
   ```

In complex projects you will need to provide a bunch or arguments to `javac` to make it compile.