# Compiling a Mex file for Java

Tags: java, matlab, mex

I found a java based TCP-IP system for matlab which might fix many problems I've been having with multiple and uninterruptible connections. However I'm stumped on how to get it working. I have compiled code under linux plenty of times but never on windows.

The code I'm trying to compile is located [here](https://github.com/kyamagu/matlab-tcpip) and it states:

**Build**

**Compile MEX files and Java helpers by the attached Makefile.**

```
make
```

The question is how? I thought of using Visual studio command prompt but I end up getting an error:

> makefile(8) : fatal error U1036: syntax error : too many names to left of '='

Which suggests either I have to edit the makefile or I'm using the wrong compiler. And I have no knowledge of Java so I don't even know where to begin when compiling it.

edit: Updating to show what code is in the makefile

```
MATLABDIR ?= /usr/local/matlab
MATLAB := $(MATLABDIR)/bin/matlab
MEX := $(MATLABDIR)/bin/mex
MEXEXT := $(shell $(MATLABDIR)/bin/mexext)
MEXSOURCES := $(wildcard private/*.cc)
MEXTARGETS := $(patsubst %.cc,%.$(MEXEXT),$(MEXSOURCES))
CLASSPATH := java
JAVASOURCES := $(wildcard java/matlab_tcpip/*.java)
JAVATARGETS = $(patsubst %.java,%.class,$(JAVASOURCES))
JARFILE = java/matlab_tcpip.jar

all: $(JARFILE) $(MEXTARGETS)

%.$(MEXEXT):%.cc
    $(MEX) $< -output $@

$(JARFILE): $(JAVATARGETS)
    jar cvf $@ -C java matlab_tcpip/
    jar i $@

%.class:%.java
    javac -cp $(CLASSPATH) $<

test: $(JARFILE)
    echo "run test/runServer.m" | $(MATLAB) -nodisplay & \
    echo "run test/runClient.m" | $(MATLAB) -nodisplay

clean:
    rm $(MEXTARGETS) java/matlab_tcpip/*.class $(JARFILE)
```

Comment: The easiest way to compile stuff on Windows is to use [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com). It is a (more-or-less) Posix environment on top of Windows, and you can build most Unix projects without any modifications. You'll still have to adjust the Makefile to point to the right MATLAB directory, of course.

Comment: I don't know if that will work as it seems I need to compile it in java

Comment: I don’t see why not. From Cygwin you can also run any Windows tools. There is no reason you wouldn’t be able to compile Java. — Ah! Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259282/run-and-compile-java-code-in-cygwin